# Reg Sqlite binding

Tags: c++, sqlite

i am working on sqlite db using c++ front end. when i try to bind variable in the query , it is giving the following error.

here is the code

```
           for(vector<vector<string> >::iterator it = result.begin(); it < result.end(); ++it)
            {
                vector<string> row = *it;                     
                **sqlite3_bind_text(statement,2,[row.at(1) string],-1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);**                     
                int result = sqlite3_step(statement);
            }
```

bolded line is giving the problem which is " cannot convert ‘Database::InitialSync()::’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘3’ to ‘int sqlite3_bind_text(sqlite3_stmt*, int, const char*, int, void (*)(void*))’"

Can anybody help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, just use

```
sqlite3_bind_text(statement,2, row[1].c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

if you need to bing the first (not the zeroth) value from the 'row' array.

If I misunderstand your, please, clarify the thing you want to do, not just this compilation error. I mean what parameter do you want to bind.